# Oracle SQL, SELECT clause using &input

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I have an quite simple query

```
SELECT id FROM table where ID in &data
```

When I run this SQL I am prompted to type in some values to `&data`.

I would like to be able to select several id's using this. i.e. &data = "11,12,13"

but then I get an error `ORA-00933`.

Ive tried with:

```
11,12,13
'11,12,13' -> ORA-01722
'11','12','13'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add `()`:

```
SELECT id FROM table where ID in (&data)
```

the input values should be `'11,12,13'`

or try to add `('')`:

```
SELECT id FROM table where ID in (&data)
```

the input values should be `11,12,13`